# Common patterns for allowing JS libraries to support plugins

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

As the library designer, what are some common patterns/tricks for writing your library so that it can be extended via external plugins?

Here are some things plugins might want to do:

Add logging support to the library's basic methods. eg make one of the library's core (private) methods output to the console for debug purposes - allowing me to remove all console.log calls from https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/master/annyang.js

Add visual cues and effects to library events. eg display a speaker icon when a SpeechRecognition library starts listening.

My first instinct would be to expose those as events, to which callbacks can be attached from a plugin (eg onCommandLoaded, onCommandMatched, onSpeechRecognized, etc.) In other words, allowing plugins to SUBscribe to events PUBlished by the library. But this can easily grow and grow as more features are requested, and doesn't allow for a plugin to extend a functionality I didn't anticipate (I'm still unsure whether that is a bad thing or not).

Any ideas?